# where does apt or dpkg store the list of installed packages?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg

I know I can do

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

to see a list of installed packages.  However I have a hard drive that doesn't boot but most files appear to be intact.  Is there a way I can get the list of packages that were installed off this broken hard drive without figuring out how to boot a system from it?  Where does dpkg store this information?

The old system was Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have mounted the old drive, it may be possible to use the `--root` option to run `dpkg` commands on the broken system directly ex. `dpkg --root=/mnt/oldroot --get-selections`

Comment: @steeldriver please make this an answer so I can mark it as the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your question is that it is stored in the file `/var/lib/dpkg/status` (at least by default).

However, if you have mounted the old system, then it may be possible to run `dpkg --get-selections` on it directly, using the `--root` switch. From `man dpkg`:

> ```
>    --root=dir
>           Changing  root  changes  instdir  to  «dir»  and   admindir   to
>           «dir/var/lib/dpkg».
> ```

So for example

```
dpkg --root=/mnt/oldroot --get-selections
```

If your old system had a separate `/var` or `/var/lib` partition, these will also need to be appropriately mounted as well.